# Drupal module add Google Maps API script

Tags: javascript, google-maps, drupal-6

I am developing a system which heavily utilizes Google Maps v3.

I am working on a module which uses jQuery to dynamically insert my map div - that works.

But including the remote Google API JS script dynamically is proving difficult. I am trying the following in my modules hook_init():

```
drupal_add_js( "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" );
drupal_add_js( "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'></script>");
```

In either case, my app doesn't load. Including the script definition into page.tpl.php manually works of course.

Answer (score 0):

Due to [this](http://drupal.org/node/224333#drupal_add_js_external) topic, you should use 
`drupal_set_html_head();` for D6. in D7 you can load external js by passing "external" scope, but this is not backported to for D6.